# How can i edit my python script so it can select the whole text of a fasta sequence?

Tags: python, fasta

I have 2 files: one is a text file that contains a series of IDs, and the other is a multifasta file that contains fasta sequences corresponding to the IDs in the first file. I have a python a script that can select the matching IDs from both files. It looks like this:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

fasta=SeqIO.parse("fasta1.fasta","fasta")
seq_dict={}

for record in fasta:
    seq_dict[record.id]=record.seq

#print (seq_dict)
for line in open("names","r"):
    line=line.strip()
    print(line)

for cle in seq_dict.keys():
    print(cle)
```

I need to edit my script so it can select the text of the sequence next to its corresponding ID. Can you help me please to do that? Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean `for cle, value in seq_dict.items(): print(cle, value)`?

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired output?

Comment: Please add samples of your input files. Please do not assume people will know what fasta/multifasta is (is it even relevant to the question?).

Comment: @Bazingaa Yes that's it and next to the matched ID i need to extract the text of the sequence also.

Comment: @YuvalG my desired output should be like this: >tr|A0A1D3TK72|A0A1D3TK72_PLAFA 
MSNLIEKIKKHMEIGSKVCNTTPEINTSMASPNLKEIKVDIDMEMEEGIIDEDIMTPRVFDRTKKGMGVKNFVMNKSENKEKRKEINAKNDEYSSAYDSSSNRSMTKRARKGNAKESRDYVESHKDSEAENIENAETVENIGSVDNDEYVQSGENGDSGENDQNDQNGQRGFSPGNDDSVSTNERMDPPEECGGIEGIGNSNHGDECGDEFGDKCGDECGDEFGDKCGDECGDEYGNEHGNEHGNEYSMEKEDACPFVNITWQTPKKSNVGLYYSGIDNPSTLKKYKTPCEMDMLHPDES

Comment: @petre Sorry about the confusion. My input files are: the first one is an IDs file:     >tr|Q8IM60|Q8IM60_PLAF7
>tr|C6KSM0|C6KSM0_PLAF7
>tr|Q8IAM1|Q8IAM1_PLAF7.                                                                                    The second output files contains many fasta sequence like this: >tr|A0A1D3TK72|A0A1D3TK72_PLAFA MSNLIEKIKKHMEIGSKVCNTTPEINTSMASPNLKEIKVDIDMEMEEGIIDEDIMTPRVFDRTKKGMGVKNFVMNKSENKEKRKEINAKNDEYSSAYDSSSNRSMTKRARKGNAKESRDYVESHKDSEAENIENAETVENIGSVDNDEYVQSGENGDSGENDQNDQNGQRGFSPGNDDSVSTNERMDPPEECGGIEGIGNSNHGDECGDEFGDKCGDECGDEFGDKCGDECGDEYGNEHGNEHGNEYSMEKEDACP

Comment: I think that what you need is `read()` instead of `parse()`. Edit: scratch that, `read()` is for files with exactly one record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing a bit with Bio.SeqIO, I concluded that @Bazingaa is probably correct. Adapted your code like so:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

fasta=SeqIO.parse("fasta1.fasta","fasta")
seq_dict={}

for record in fasta:
    seq_dict[record.id]=record.description

#print (seq_dict)
for line in open("names","r"):
    line=line.strip()
    print(line)

for cle, desc in seq_dict.items():
    print(cle)
    print(desc)
```

You seem to be new to python, so here's what I did:

- instead of keeping record.seq, i stored record.description
- `for a, b in <some dictionary>.items()` will iterate through the dictionary items returning key, value pairs into the a, b variables

Hope this helps.

Edit:

Here's a somewhat more "pythonic" version. I don't really understand what fasta is so I assumed you'd want to read lines from names, take the 'tr|something|something' part as ids (without the leading '>') and print out the ones from 'fasta1.fasta' if they're in names:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

fasta = SeqIO.parse("fasta1.fasta","fasta")

# read all the names
with open("names", "r") as f:  # this takes care to close the file afterwards
  names = [line.strip().lstrip('>') for line in f]
print("Names: ", names)

for record in fasta:
    print("Record:", record.id)
    if record.id in names:                                                                                            
        print("Matching record:", record.id, record.seq, record.description)
```

Comment: i have tried the first script and i have got only the IDs of the first file next the IDs of the fasta sequences without the texts of the sequences. For the second script i've got this as an output:                                                                   
                               ('Names: ', ['tr|Q8IM60|Q8IM60_PLAF7', 'tr|C6KSM0|C6KSM0_PLAF7', 'tr|Q8IAM1|Q8IAM1_PLAF7'])
('Record:', 'tr|Q8IEB1|Q8IEB1_PLAF7')
('Record:', 'tr|C6KSV2|C6KSV2_PLAF7')
('Record:', 'tr|Q8IIJ2|Q8IIJ2_PLAF7')

Comment: @YasmineOchi: Well yes, I've added some prints to show what it does in between. If that's all the output, that none of the records in fasta1 match the ids in names. Again, I've no idea what fasta is so my assumptions might be wrong, sorry for that. From the examples you've given there does not seem to be any match between the two, so I just assumed that record.id should be a line in names. If you need something else, please clarify it in your question.

Comment: ok thank you so much for your help. I think i will check my fasta1 file again. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract only the items from the `names` file, it is probably more efficient to read the names into memory first.

```
from Bio import SeqIO

wanted = dict()
with open("names","r") as lines:
    for line in lines:
        wanted[line.strip()] = 1

for record in SeqIO.parse("fasta1.fasta","fasta"):
    if record.id in wanted:
        print(record.seq)
```

Comment: I really don't know if this is what you are actually asking.

Comment: Thank you for your help but unfortunally it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

fasta=SeqIO.parse("fasta1.fasta","fasta")
seq_dict = {}

for record in fasta:
    seq_dict[record.id.strip()] = record.seq

with open("names","r") as lines:
    for line in lines:
        l = line.strip().lstrip('<')
        if l in seq_dict:
            print(l) # ID
            print(seq_dict[l])  # sequence
```

Note this assumes that the IDs obtained from the fasta file are the same as the IDs in the name file. If this is not the case, please provide further detail of exactly what each of the two files contains (with examples)

Comment: i've tried your script but i didn't get any output. Any ideas why is that? Thank you again.

Comment: @YugalG By executing this edited script, unfortunately i didn't get any output.

Comment: then perhaps I am misunderstanding what you are trying to accomplish. 
What I understood is this: 

You have a names file that has IDs and another file of fasta records. You want to print the ID and the sequence for every record in the fasta file if the ID is also in the names file. 

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes but the second file contains sequences corresponding to the IDs in the files names not records. I want a script that reads the IDs in the names files than search for sequences having matching IDs for the IDs in the first file. Then the output should be the matching IDs with its sequences.

Comment: Yes. That's what this script should do. I made another small edit to the code.
How many IDs are in your name file? Are you sure there are matching IDs between the fasta file and the names file? It seems your names file only has three IDs. Maybe there are no matches in the fasta file for these?

Comment: There more than 500 IDs in the original file, and yes there is matching IDs between the 2 files.

Comment: Your output to petre's answer was ('Names: ', ['tr|Q8IM60|Q8IM60_PLAF7', 'tr|C6KSM0|C6KSM0_PLAF7', 'tr|Q8IAM1|Q8IAM1_PLAF7']), so only three IDs are being printed from your names file. Maybe you aren't loading it correctly, or there may be some other error. Unfortunately without your full code and files it will be very hard to help you figure out where the problem is.

Comment: @YuvalG I've just noticed your solution having the same approach and assumptions, so mine is redundant. Sorry about that.

Comment: No harm done. If you manage to figure out why the OPs code is behaving the way it is, I'm at a loss

Comment: @YuvalG No worries! Thank you for all the help you've been giving me.I really apprecite it :)